# ApplicationId missing when calling Application Usage Detail Event Report

Tags: office365, office365api, office365-restapi

I'm using the Office 365 Graph API to get a number of reports. I'm attempted to get application usage detail events from the following endpoint, utilizing an applicationId that I took from the results of the applicationUsageSummaryEvents report:

https://graph.windows.net/acme/reports/applicationUsageDetailEvents?api-version=beta&applicationId=13d54852-ae25-4f0b-abcd-b09eea89f431

Unfortunately, I continue to get the following error, even after trying every permutation of "applicationId" I could think of.

{
  "error":{
    "code":"","message":"applicationId is required"
  }
}

I've looked everywhere I can think of online to try to figure out the call. From [here](https://graph.windows.net/api/reports/$metadata#applicationUsageDetailEvents) I know that the schema shows it as "applicationId":

```
<EntityType Name="ApplicationUsageDetailEvent">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="id" />
</Key>
<Property Name="id" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
<Property Name="eventTime" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Nullable="false" />
<Property Name="maxActivityTimeStamp" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Nullable="false"     />
<Property Name="applicationId" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false" />
<Property Name="numberOfClicks" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
<Property Name="totalDay30Count" Type="Edm.Int32" />
<Property Name="totalDay7Count" Type="Edm.Int32" />
<Property Name="totalHour24Count" Type="Edm.Int32" />
<Property Name="userName" Type="Edm.String" />
 </EntityType>
```

Can anyone tell me how to properly pass the application ID into this REST call to get back results?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's an odata API, you would need to pass in the appId thru the $filter parameter:
+ "&$filter=applicationId eq fe3f7e7b-0044-4690-8ea5-1e9c6be5d026"

Your url would look like:
https://graph.windows.net/acme/reports/applicationUsageDetailEvents?api-version=beta&$filter=applicationId eq 13d54852-ae25-4f0b-abcd-b09eea89f431